# JQuery - check checkboxes based on select list value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Im very, very new to jquery.  Im trying to do something that most likely seems elementary to most of the gurus here, but I think I have been messing with it for so long, that I must be overlooking something very simple.

I have a large list of checkboxes (85 in total) that need to be checked based on the value selected in a select list.  Both the select list and the checkboxes are created dynamically via an ASP page/database query.

Link to fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/v9p5C/21/

HTML:

```
<select id="roleID">
    <option data-filter=''>ID</option>
    <option data-filter='200'>200</option>
    <option data-filter='300'>300</option>
    <option data-filter='400'>400</option>
</select>
<BR>
<BR>
<input type="checkbox" data-tags='["200"]'>Create
<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-tags='["200,300"]'>Edit
<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-tags='["200","300, 400"]'>View
<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-tags='["200"]'>Delete
<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-tags='["200"]'>Archive
<br>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', function (e) {

        var filter = $(this).data('filter');

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            var $checkbox = $(this);
            var tags = $checkbox.data('tags');
            $.each(tags, function () {
                if (filter == this) $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: I recommend not using the quotes around the data-filter options because you've mixed up a couple of brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery will need to look more like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#roleID').on('change', function (e) {

        var filter = $(this).val();

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
        $('input[type="checkbox"][data-tags*="'+filter+'"]').attr('checked','checked');

    });
});
```

This is a very simple way of creating that functionality. You can view the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/kjnoovL0/1/

Comment: There's room for error in this setup, depending on the values you're checking for. I used the CSS3 selector ([attr*=value]) because it's much easier for newbies, I assume. However, if you have more complex values to check for, you may want to use indexOf() or something similar. Good luck.

Comment: turns out I need to change this somewhat.  New to stackoverflow as well, so I am not sure how to follow up.  I guess I need to slightly alter what I am doing as I need to have a load defaults checkbox instead.  I kind of have it working in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kjnoovL0/5/), but the checkbox isnt staying checked.

Comment: What is the load defaults checkbox supposed to do?

Comment: I noticed that you forgot to put quotes around roleID. var filter = $('#roleID').val();

Comment: basically, only if the loadDEfaults checkbox is checked, the corresponding options get checked. This is what I am playing with now: http://jsfiddle.net/kjnoovL0/17/.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you're trying to do. How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/kjnoovL0/25/

Comment: I ended up changing it from checkboxes to links with a few more options.  It works great in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjnoovL0/51/, but the loadDefaults isnt working in my actual code, but the previouslySave, selectAll, and selectNone functions are working great.  I feel like it has somethign to do with the "var filter = $(roleID).val();" line, but I cant seem to figure out what it is.  If I add quotes, var filter = $("roleID").val();it breaks it in fiddle and my code, so I dont think thats it?

Comment: FACEPALM!  had a typo in the ID of the roleID selectlist!

Answer (score 2):

the `var filter = $(this).data('filter');` line was attempting to get the data-filter value from the select element, not the selected option element.  Here's how you would grab the selection option's data-filter:

```
var filter = $('option:selected', this).data('filter');
```

updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/v9p5C/52/

(there were a couple of other minor bugs in the fiddle that are also fixed)

Comment: Problem with this method is that if he checks something like 200 after checking 300, the two middle ones will not be selected.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v9p5C/54/ I just updated your fiddle here and there. I also changed the HTML data-filter options to not include quotes. Since these are numbers, they aren't really necessary.

Comment: agree, I was trying to keep it close to the OP's fiddle